# Impossible to use array value

Tags: macros, color

I am trying to use the value of an array in a function. But it does not work.
Any ideas?

See below my LaTeX code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{arrayjob}

\newarray\Color
\readarray{Color}{blue&red&orange&violet}

\begin{document}

\Color(2)
\textcolor{\the\Color(2)}{moi}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you using `xcolor` too for `\textcolor`?

Answer (score 5):

It can't work. The command `\textcolor` does expand its argument looking for a color, but unfortunately the extraction of a value from `\Color` requires actions that are not allowed when doing "pure expansion".

As the manual explains that you have to do in an indirect way:

```
\checkColor(2)\textcolor{\cachedata}{moi}
```

The operation `\checkColor` extracts the value and places it as the expansion of `\cachedata` and now the expansion by `\textcolor` is possible.

Note that you should be using `arrayjobx` instead of `arrayjob`, which has serious problems with LaTeX.

---

### A different strategy with LaTeX3 macros

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xarraynew}{m O{&} m}
 {
  \xarray_define:nnn {#1} {#2} {#3}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \xarray_define:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \seq_new:c { g_xarray_ #1 _seq }
  \seq_gset_split:cnn { g_xarray_ #1 _seq } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_gset_split:Nnn { c }

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\xarrayget}{m m}
 {
  \xarray_get:nn { #1 } { #2 - 1 }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \xarray_get:nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_item:cn { g_xarray_ #1 _seq } { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\xarraynew{Color}{blue&red&orange&violet}

\begin{document}

\textcolor{\xarrayget{Color}{2}}{moi}

\end{document}
```

The user level commands are `\xarraynew` that takes two arguments: the array name and the data. It's possible also to specify a different delimiter, so

```
\xarraynew{Color}[,]{blue,red,orange,violet}
```

would be equivalent.

You can extract a value with `\xarrayget`, which takes again as argument the array name and the position.

Comment: Ah just seconds ..... :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I am surprising that Latex3 is working on my configuration. I though that I had only Latex2.

Comment: @latexalpha It's really `expl3`, which will become LaTeX3 in some years.

Answer (score 3):

As indicated by @egreg, you need to use *expandable* definitions. I would use a simple expandable lookup as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}


\def\Colorarray{{1}{blue}{2}{red}{3}{orange}{4}{violet}}

\def\getcolor#1{\expandafter\xgetcolor\Colorarray{#1}{}\getcolor{#1}}

\def\xgetcolor#1#2#3\getcolor#4{%
\ifnum#4=#1 #2\else\xgetcolor#3\getcolor{#4}\fi}


\begin{document}

\textcolor{\getcolor{2}}{moi}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your proposition working fine. But I do not understand it at all

Comment: I understand your suggestion using tracingall. Thanks a lot